# Deezer IOS Genre top songs search

Tags: ios, deezer

Is there any way to search top genre songs ie. Top songs in "Dance" in Deezer API?
For example when I use http://api.deezer.com/genre/113/artists system sends only the artist list related with the Genre Id. But I need top songs related with the Genre. iTunes is supplying this kind of information but I couldn't find this solution in Deezer. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://developers.deezer.com/api/chart/tracks

Usage example:
`http://api.deezer.com/chart/113/tracks`

Comment: Yes, this was the solution I was looking for... Thank you. Also Do you know how to get other country Genre charts? Because when I use rest client, it shows me local genre charts.

Comment: @icould: API results are always local, you can't choose other countries, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your support.